# Install path in property

Tags: wix

The installation path is dependent on the key in the registry. I wish it was not thought install path hardcoded.

Currently it looks like this:

```
<Property Id = "INSTALLAPP" Value = "C: \ Program Files \ ABC \ DEF \ Application" /> // default install path
```

And I would like to:

```
<Property Id = "INSTALLAPP" Value = "[ProgramFiles64Folder] \ ABC \ DEF \ Application" />
```

How to change it?

Comment: You may need to expand your question. First, use [ProgramFilesFolder] in the 32-bit example anyway. It looks like you are looking for a WiX RegistrySearch that will set INSTALLAPP  to the location in the registry? If so, look at WiX RegistrySearch, such as this example http://blogs.msdn.com/b/syamp/archive/2012/09/30/wix-search-for-install-path-from-registry.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The values of a property in the property table are simple strings, so adding another property won't help as it doesn't get resolved.
As you are using a value from the registry, a `RegistrySearch` like @PhilDW proposed would be the way to go, e.g.:

```
    <Property Id="INSTALLLAPP">
      <RegistrySearch Id="GetInstallApp" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyProduct" Name="InstallLocation" Type="raw" />
    </Property>
```